# Capture Console info to file in python

Tags: python, stdout

I would like to capture all the info that gets captured in the console to a file. and not just the console print() function. There is code on stack overflow of how to redirect the `print()` to a file but not if errors happened. Like if you have a program that will give an error like below. it will gave a

```
indexError: List index out of rang
```

I would like to capture all console info to a file without writing try and exception everywhere.

my overall task would be to use pyInstaller to create a program with a log file and capture the console in a log to know where the program broke.

```py
list= ["hello","Bey"]
counter=0
while counter < 100:
    print(list[counter])
    counter=counter+1

#What the console print out. 
#print(list[counter])
#IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Maybe try `stderr`

Comment: try: `python yourscript.py > out.txt 2> errout.txt` (2> is to redirect stderr)

Comment: But where will i type this . in my cod or in cmd when running my code. ?

Comment: ```python youscript.py |& tee output.txt```, if you are on windows, you can probably do it in cmd like that ```powershell "python yourscript.py |& tee output.txt```

Comment: @ FelipeSulser how will I ad this in my code for when i create my app using pyInstaller

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the logging module for this task. But, still if you want to redirect all the console output to files then you can redirect both the file descriptors for stdout and stderr to 2 different files. So, the console command to invoke the python script will look like

```
python myscript.py 1>C:\Python27\out_log.log 2>C:\Python27\err_log.log
```

After execution out_log.log will have "hello" and "Bey" while the exception will be redirected to the err_log.log file. In this case, nothing will get printed on the console.

Comment: the err_log works. but how will i implement it in the code for when i create the app using the pyInstaller ?

Comment: how will I ad this in my code for when i create my app using pyInstaller

Comment: you include a batch file that has `myscript.exe 1> out.log 2> err.log` and tell your users to launch the batch file instead of the exe directly.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel If i do it to a small app it generates the log. But as soon as i do it to my main big app. it does not capture the errors. only after a view random clicks it generates a bunch of errors. it is as if waits for a bunch of errors before it prints to the file.

Comment: @BernardtSpies, that's called buffering.

Answer (score 0):

pip install logging
Logging is your friend 
https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html